# OpenGL: far objects appearing on top of near objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I'm trying to put together a quick demo using iOS GLKit to render a retail store map using OpenGL using the source CAD files.  I was able to render the walls and aisles in 2D, then programmatically add some artificial depth to create a series of cubes.  All of this looks fine when looking top down, but I noticed that when I turned on the floor (with a z-value that is well below the aisles and walls that some of those objects are actually rendered under the floor:

[image: aisles below the floor]

...however if you rotate the model you can see that nothing is actually below the floor and some of the aisles are rendering outside of the wall:

[image]

You can view the code at [StoreMapGLKitViewController.m](https://bitbucket.org/rwrife/storemapgl/raw/c36902a4188bc6bddb9bbbbbd74602e6112dc273/StoreMapGL/StoreMapGLKitViewController.m), it all seems pretty simple to me, but I'm sure I'm making some kind of OpenGL rookie mistake.

Comment: Here's a video of the weird clipping issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Vls6gwJvFQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up that the depth buffer wasn't setup correcting so the depth test wasn't doing anything.  Adding the code below fixed it.

```
GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you are messing with the Z values, and z = 0 for all the things, I'd imagine you'd still be able to see some of your walls and aisles, but they would also hang out the bottom a bit. As long as you don't care about that (its a demo, right) then that should be fine for now I would thenk.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, but I shouldn't be able to see the aisles on top of the walls from the outside.